# Active record create 3 multiple level tables in a single action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My model structure is student.enrolments.disabilities. Each is 1 to many. I have an enrolment application form which contains field data from all three tables. None of the records exist but I want to create all three tables in a single action. I have done this at 2 levels previously but not three.

Can I do something like this?

```
 @student.create( assign some fields )

 @student.enrolments.create( assign some fields )  

 @student.enrolments.disabilities.create( assign some fields )

 @student.enrolments.prior_educational_achievements.create( assign some fields )

 @student.save
```

Would this work? Is there a better way? Do I need to save the student like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with nested attributes. Here are some useful links: 
Documentation:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html 
RailsCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=nested+forms

Comment: I don't want to do this with nested forms as I save the application first as it may be incomplete. The application is a separate model, Later I construct the records from the various fields manually.

Comment: save the application? I don't understand

Comment: Save the application for enrolment form with its data.